# Как сделать всплывающее окно с размытием фона страницы?

Tags: javascript, css

На сайте http://callbackhunter.com/ при клике на телефон в правом нижнем углу появляется окно, и фон за окном размывается. Как можно реализовать такую штуку?

Пытался сделать с помощью фильтра blur, вешая свойства размытия на body,
но тогда у меня и окно тоже полностью размыто. Сделать только размытие фона никак не получается.

Comment: а если сделать всплывающее окно как 2 слоя: фон и само окно?
Фону указать прозрачность и поставить фильтр.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, если вы посмотрите на разметку сайта, то увидите, что основной контент обёрнут в отдельный элемент (*id="global-zeroclipboard-html-bridge"*), а модальное окно - находится за пределами этой обёртки.

Comment: Если окно, как 2 слоя, то это бессмысленно. В блоке должен быть контент. Именно внутреннему контенту применяется фильтр. А так для фона он применится, но на контенте не будет видно фильтра.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/4058/deonis, по поводу элемента понял. Получается, обойти это нельзя, если нет возможности контент обернуть в див, а окно в другой блок вынести?

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, я не говорил, что обойти это нельзя, но каких-то простых способов - не знаю.

Comment: Deonis, я суть понял. Как там работает. Там яваскрипт всем дивам класс с фильтром дописывает. Как можно на странице всем дивам яваскриптом классы прописать? Кроме нескольких заданных.